# Batch Delete items with Content Provider in Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I'm trying to batch delete some items in a table.

```
    String ids = { "1", "2", "3" };

    mContentResolver.delete(uri, MyTables._ID + "=?", ids);
```

However I keep getting this following error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many bind arguments.  3 arguments were provided but the statement needs 1 arguments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error occurs because you have a single placeholder (?) in your where clause, while you pass three arguments. You should do:

```
String ids = { "1", "2", "3" };

mContentResolver.delete(uri, MyTables._ID + "=? OR " + MyTables._ID + "=? OR " + MyTables._ID + "=?", ids);
```

I do not know if SQLite supports the IN clause, if so you could also do:

```
String ids = { "1, 2, 3" };

mContentResolver.delete(uri, MyTables._ID + " IN (?)", ids);
```

Comment: Thanks Jan. I guess I had a fundamental misunderstanding of how the selectionArgs worked. My ids can be variable in size. So your second solution looks more appealing. However, I'm afraid that doesn't seem to work either.

I suppose I could just check my size and loop to construct that where clase, but that doesn't seem nice :(

Answer (score 21):

You can use [ContentProviderOperation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderOperation.html) for batch deletion/insertion/update in one transaction. It's much nicer you don't have to concatenate strings. It also should be very efficient. For deletion:

```
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operations = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    ContentProviderOperation operation;

    for (Item item : items) {

        operation = ContentProviderOperation
                .newDelete(ItemsColumns.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(ItemsColumns.UID + " = ?", new String[]{item.getUid()})
                .build();

        operations.add(operation);
    }

    try {
        contentResolver.applyBatch(Contract.AUTHORITY, operations);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {

    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {

    }
```

Comment: Correct, I have this query whether `BulkInsert` is faster that `ApplyBatch`

Comment: for sms operation the Authority is `"sms"`

Comment: for song operation, the AUTHORITY id 'MediaStore.AUTHORITY'

Answer (score 0):

```
String sqlCommand = String.format("DELETE FROM %s WHERE %s IN (%s);", TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID, 1,2,3);

db.execSQL(sqlCommand);
```