# Android Parse: SQLiteException: when pinning

Tags: android, sqlite, parse-platform

I have an AsyncTask that performs a series of queries to Parse and then pins the results to the local datastore.

The problem is that after several of the queries are performed, eventually all subsequent calls to ParseObject.pinAll(listOfParseObjects) fail with:

> SQLiteException: too many SQL variables (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM ParseObjects WHERE uuid IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,... etc.

I've tried lowering the query limit down from 1000 to 100 in steps, but it happens regardless.

Please help.  Thanks!

Comment: It appears Parse is just [very](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877247/how-to-fix-android-database-cursorwindowallocationexception-crash) [buggy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007058/closing-all-cursors-associated-with-sqlite-database).

Comment: OK, sounds like it's time to submit this as a bug to Parse.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use "IN" , note that there is a max of 999 items to be mentioned there. Otherwise you will get  `SQLiteException: too many SQL variables" when using " IN (...)"`:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192284727#comment2

> Its based on how large the collection is, Android's SQLite has a limit
> of 999 binding query arguments, so a collection with more than 999
> items fail.

I've requested to solve it better here (Please consider starring) :

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192384616

So, you need to split it into multiple requests (can be in a transaction when possible).

This is true for all operations on DB, meaning insert, delete and select. Doesn't matter which API you use.

Example of how to use it in Room for deletion:

```
@WorkerThread
@Query("DELETE FROM some_table WHERE phone_number IN (:phoneNumbersToRemove)")
protected abstract fun removePhoneNumbersImp(phoneNumbersToRemove: Collection<String>): Int

@WorkerThread
@Transaction
open fun removePhoneNumbers(phoneNumbersToRemove: Set<String>) {
    if (phoneNumbersToRemove.isEmpty())
        return
    phoneNumbersToRemove.asSequence().chunked(999).forEach {
        removePhoneNumbersImp(it)
    }
}
```