# How to bulk delete events from the Device calendar by app id, and not by an array of event ids

Tags: android, android-calendar

This is how I create calendar events from within my app:

```
for(CalendarEventDescriptor calendarEventDescriptor : calendarEventDescriptors.values()) {
                if(calendarEventDescriptor.startMilliseconds>now){

                    values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, calendarEventDescriptor.startMilliseconds);
                    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, calendarEventDescriptor.endMilliseconds);
                    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, calendarEventDescriptor.title);
                    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, calendarEventDescriptor.description);

                    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
                    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone);
                    uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
                    calendarEventDescriptor.eventId = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
                }
            }
```

At the time or writing, I store an array of all the event Ids that I've created, so that when the user flicks a switch, I loop through them and delete them from the Calendar.

```
for(long eventId : eventIds) {
                if(eventId>0){
                    Uri deleteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, eventId);
                    rowsDeleted += application.getContentResolver().delete(deleteUri, null, null);
                }
            }
```

It occurred to me that it might be possible to put a custom value for one of the `CalendarContract.Events.` columns so that I can do the deletion for all of the events at once, and that I don't have to remember their ids (I always delete them all, never delete certain ones)

Is that possible and which `CalendarContract.Events.` column should I use and how do I do the deletion then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice question! I agree, that extra-property in `ContentValues` is the way to go in this case.
I've done it by re-using `CalendarContract.Events.CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE`, as something invisible for the user and, so far, no side effects found:

So I'm creating Events, like you do:

```
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, ...);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, ...);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, ...);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, ....);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE, getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
        cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

And then once I need to delete all of them, I call:

```
    Cursor cursor = cr
            .query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI,
                   new String[] { CalendarContract.Events._ID, CalendarContract.Events.CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE },
                   null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    String idsToDelete = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
        // it might be also smart to check CALENDAR_ID here
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageName().equals(cursor.getString(1))) {
            idsToDelete += String.format("_ID = %s OR ", cursor.getString(0));
        }

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    if (idsToDelete.endsWith(" OR ")) {
        idsToDelete = idsToDelete.substring(0, idsToDelete.length()-4);
    }

    cr.delete(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, idsToDelete, null);
```

I hope, it helps

Comment: So there is no way to actually delete events without using a loop, just by saying "hey, delete all events corresponding to this app package at once"? I really want to prevent looping, because it takes forever deleting 300 events for example

Comment: And the good side of this is that I do not have to save the event ids in the app storage and I can delete previous events from an uninstalled app, whenever I please, right?

Comment: @J.K. That's right, once Events have the property set, you can delete it any time and, actually, even from the different app. I'll think if it's possible to bulk it and reach out

Comment: @J.K. I've updated code, now it's without loop for deleting. Check it out!

Comment: Thank you a lot! I will be able to award the bounty in 20 hours

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ContentProviderOperation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderOperation.html) with [applyBatch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#applyBatch(java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.content.ContentProviderOperation%3E)) to perform multiple deletes/inserts in a single transaction.

Check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22823592/1011435) for code sample.

Answer (score 0):

after a long long research, I've got a sort of new doc of google calendar
you can add multiple args to a selection allowing you to find all desired rows and delete them all at once

```
val operationList = ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>()
var contentProviderOperation: ContentProviderOperation

appointments.forEach {
   contentProviderOperation = ContentProviderOperation
  .newDelete(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
  .withSelection(CalendarContract.Events.ORIGINAL_SYNC_ID + " =?", arrayOf(it.id))
  .build()

  operationList.add(contentProviderOperation)
}

contentResolver.applyBatch(CalendarContract.AUTHORITY, operationList)
```